# MATLAB: inverse of absolute value

Tags: matlab

Is there a function in MATLAB that performs the inverse of an absolute value (e.g., entering `3` gives `[3,-3]`; entering `-3` gives the same).

Comment: Um, there is NO value x such that the absolute value of x is -3. An inverse does not exist. As far as writing a function that yields both solutions, that seems trivial. If x is positive, return both x and -x. WTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function ret=inv_abs(num)
     ret=[abs(num) -abs(num)];
```

Comment: @user001: Sometimes it's just easier to build a 2 line function than look for one build in...

Comment: I think you need `[abs(num) -abs(num)]` to match the original question.

Comment: @Edric: Sure, I'll add it in.

Comment: Why would Matlab possibly have a built in "function" to do this?